# What is the 3rd parameter meant to look/be like XInputGetBatteryInformation()

Tags: c++, xinput

Sorry if I messed up this post or something, my first time ever posting on Stackoverflow, I'd usually ask a discord server for help but they don't do C++, I'm pretty new to C++ and I am trying to develop a Bakkesmod plugin, it uses XInput, the idea is that it updates you when the controller battery level changes, though I'm not sure how I would get the battery information for it, it mentions to send a pointer but that's a bit tricky for me, I'd love if someone explained it. [API Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMr6T.png)

Comment: Why don't you try to implement a sample program that does nothing but make use of this API call, and then ask if you have specific questions, first? It's always a better learning experience if you try to figure these things out yourself, first. What have you tried, already? Do you understand what a "pointer" is, in C++, and how it works? If not, perhaps it will be more productive to focus on learning C++ core fundamentals, first, so there's a solid grasp on the basics, before attempting to explore complicated operating system API calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a variable of type [`XINPUT_BATTERY_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/xinput/ns-xinput-xinput_battery_information) and pass a pointer to it.

```
XINPUT_BATTERY_INFORMATION my_battery;
XInputGetBatteryInformation(user_index, dev_type, &my_battery);
// Now my_battery contains the battery information
```

If you or I were writing this function in a high-level language, we would probably write something more like

```
XINPUT_BATTERY_INFORMATION XInputGetBatteryInformation(DWORD, BYTE);
```

i.e. we would *return* the structure. However, what you see here is a common idiom in old C code, such as the WinAPI (And yes, the WinAPI is a C library, which you happen to be calling from C++ code). In older C code, functions that want to return structures larger than a word will often take an output parameter of that type instead.

```
DWORD XInputGetBatteryInformation(DWORD, BYTE, XINPUT_BATTERY_INFORMATION*);
```

(the `DWORD` return value is an error code)

This is for a couple of reasons. These functions are designed to be used in low-level environments, so by providing the caller with the ability to control *where* the result goes, we give them more control over their memory management, rather than forcing them to potentially copy a value several times to get it where it needs to be.